# I am trying to use postgres but I keep getting the following error. What could be the problem?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to using postgres.I have it installed in my computer but as soon as I try running the psql command it throws the following error;

```
postgres@lennox-ThinkPad-T470s:~$ psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have tried restarting as per the documentation but it still keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: Perhaps your port number is different than **5432** . You can retry with your correct port number such as `psql -p 5434` ...

Comment: Did you initiate a database cluster using initdb and did you start the server? Please check your logfiles.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes from installing the postgres package without a version number. Although postgres will be installed and it will be the correct version, the script to setup the cluster will not run correctly; it's a packaging issue.

If you're comfortable with postgres there is a script you can run to create this cluster and get postgres running. However, there's an easier way.

First purge the old postgres install, which will remove everything of the old installation, including databases, so back up your databases first.. The issue currently lies with 9.1 so I will assume that's what you have installed

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql-9.1
```

Now simply reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
```

Note the package name with the version number. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this :
Edit: postgresql.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
```

Enable or add:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Restart the database engine:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Also, you can check the file pg_hba.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

And add your network or host address:

```
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you should see if you have initialized your database for that go to your postgreSQL

> cd postgresql-11.18/

> bin/initdb demo

name of db cluster is demo

then start the server

> bin/pg_ctl -D demo -l logfile start

> bin/createdb demodb

then query the server

> bin/psql demodb

if you have something running on the port 5434 you can change your port while creating the db and us this command insted

> bin/createdb --port=5430 demodb

Hope this helps